# Username and password switched when using Windows Credential Manager

Tags: delphi

I got this Delphi code from SO that seemed pretty straightforward. I added some types that were missing and substituted some string handling functions that were missing, and got this.

```
unit WinCred;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

type
  CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE = packed record
    Keyword: LPTSTR;
    Flags: DWORD;
    ValueSize: DWORD;
    Value: LPBYTE;
  end;
  PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE = ^CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE;

  CREDENTIALW = packed record
    Flags: DWORD;
    Type_: DWORD;
    TargetName: LPTSTR;
    Comment: LPTSTR;
    LastWritten: FILETIME;
    CredentialBlobSize: DWORD;
    CredentialBlob: LPBYTE;
    Persist: DWORD;
    AttributeCount: DWORD;
    Attributes: PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE;
    TargetAlias: LPTSTR;
    UserName: LPTSTR;
  end;
  PCREDENTIALW = ^CREDENTIALW;

function CredWriteW(Credential: PCREDENTIALW; Flags: DWORD): Boolean; stdcall; external 'Advapi32.dll';

function CredWriteGenericCredentials(const Target, Username, Password: UnicodeString): Boolean;

implementation

function CredWriteGenericCredentials(const Target, Username, Password: UnicodeString): Boolean;
var
    Credentials: CREDENTIALW;
begin
    ZeroMemory(@Credentials, SizeOf(Credentials));
    Credentials.TargetName := PWideChar(Target); //cannot be longer than CRED_MAX_GENERIC_TARGET_NAME_LENGTH (32767) characters. Recommended format "Company_Target"
    Credentials.Type_ := CRED_TYPE_GENERIC;
    Credentials.UserName := PWideChar(Username);
    Credentials.Persist := CRED_PERSIST_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    Credentials.CredentialBlob := PByte(Password);
    Credentials.CredentialBlobSize := 2*(Length(Password)); //By convention no trailing null. Cannot be longer than CRED_MAX_CREDENTIAL_BLOB_SIZE (512) bytes
    Result := CredWriteW(@Credentials, 0);
end;

end.
```

However, when I test this function

```
[Test]
[TestCase('user', 'pass')]
procedure TestInsertCred(Username, password: string);
```

...

```
procedure TWinCredTests.TestInsertCred(Username, password: string);
begin
  Assert.IsTrue(CredWriteGenericCredentials('WinCred_Test', Username, password));
end;
```

The password shows up in the username.

[image]

This is baffling me. Shouldn't the `.Username` field take the username? And the password is written to the "credentialBlob"? I've checked all my function signatures to make sure I haven't mistakenly switched things around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using DUnitX, the first parameter to the TestCase attribute is the test case name, followed by parameters. So you're defining a test case named 'user', passing it 'pass' as UserName and nothing as Password.
Try this instead:

```
[TestCase('TestInsertCred', 'user,pass')]
```